# CSS property resize does not work correctly in Safari (dont shrink when height is set)

Tags: css, safari, resize

is there any solution how fix shrinking in Safari?
when the height is set and I try to reduce the element to the height so it doesn't work.

Firefox, Chrome works fine ...

```css
div {
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the answer here in the comments: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/r/resize/

Adding to your div `:active{ height: 0; }` solves it.

```css
div {
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div:active { 
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: However there is an issue in this approach, when you also want to support clicking inside the div - it will shrink to 0.

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for this solution, it looks good in Safari, but in Google Chrome it has strange behavior and when i click , element disappears for a while, interesting ;-))